# React Native FlatList last item visibility issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching products list and then displaying using a FlatList, my list contains 5 items and as you can see FlatList row height is variable because of varying description text. So the issue is my last item card is not completely visible maybe this is some kind of flat list issue or layout issue. Any help would be highly appreciated

```js
 renderProducts() {
        if (this.props.loading === true) {
            return (
                <View style={Styles.spinnerStyle}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.myProducts}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <Card 
                            title={item.title} 
                            image={{ 
                                uri: item.image !== null ? item.image.src :'../resImage.jpg' 
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                                {item.body_html}
                            </Text>
                            <Button
                                icon={{ name: 'code' }}
                                backgroundColor='#03A9F4'
                                fontFamily='Lato'
                                buttonStyle={{ borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0 }}
                                title='VIEW NOW' 
                            />
                      </Card>
                      )}
                />
        );
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={Styles.viewStyle}>
                    <Text style    {Styles.textStyle}>ProductsList</Text>
                </View>
                    { 
                        this.renderProducts() 
                    }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: _"...as you can see"_ We can't actually because you didn't post any code.

Comment: take a look now.

Comment: try adding padding to the bottom of `FlatList` Component. `<FlatList style={{ paddingBottom: 20 }} ... />`

Comment: Hey, is this the only solution to the problem. Adding a marginBottom works for me too, but this seems like a bit of hack, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank You. It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 175):

Set bottom padding to the `<FlatList>` content container:

```js
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}
/>
```

Comment: Why do we have to do this hack?

Comment: it worked for me, the paddingBottom I had to set it as  350( by trial and error) ( my flat list item size is higher). But how do we find the actual padding needed

Comment: This doesn't work if the content's _height is getting changed dynamically_. To make all the items of `FlatLIst` visible make sure the __parent__ `View` should have a __fixed height or width__ depending upon the FlatList direction.

Comment: you can do like this too

`<View  style={{height: '90%'}}>
<FlatList/>
</View>`

Answer (score 79):

Add `{flex: 1}` to the `View` tag housing the `Flatlist` component.

In my case,

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Header headerText={'My App'} />
      <ScreenTabs /> // this is my content with FlatList 
    </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: When I do that, my list is no longer visible at all.

Comment: If your list is not visible it might be a parent View is not flex: 1, you gotta find which parent view is not extending.

Comment: `<FlatList style={{flex: 1}}` also worked for me without any parent `<View/>`. Had to add {flex: 1} to main container view though.

Comment: @Christian give flex 1 on your parent view like this

`<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressHandler}>
            <MyItem />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>`

Worked for me

Answer (score 26):

Just wrap it in a view with flex:1

```
<ParentView style={{flex:1}
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
    // Your flatlist
    <View>
</ParentView>
```

Also, note that the each parent of this "View" in which Flatlist is wrapped must also be a View with Flex of 1. Otherwise, that your flatlist wont be visible.

Comment: "Also, note that the each parent of this "View" in which Flatlist is wrapped must also be a View with Flex of 1. Otherwise, that your flatlist wont be visible." .... very useful comment! Thanks.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Although I don't know why flex=1 solved this problem

Answer (score 18):

**Latest update:**

react-navigation has a SafeAreaView with an option to not show that bottom area.

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
<SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }} />
```

**Old response below:**

You can't see your list with flex: 1 because flex: 1 will grow the component to the parent. If the parent doesn't have flex: 1, it won't stretch to its parent or the screen. Keep in mind, however, that flex: 1 with a SafeAreaView will cause the bottom safe area to show. This will look bad if your SafeAreaView backgroundColor is a different color from your list's back ground.

My old workaround was to add an item to the bottom of the array of items, but I'm still exploring how to scroll past/under the bottom safe area margin with a FlatList (which is how I found this post to begin with).

**Update**: Using ListFooterComponent you can create even a plain white "footer" with height and/or a margin

For example (I wouldn't directly copy and paste this if I were you... there's surely a better way to detect bezel-less iPhones, especially in 2019 when we have more than one)

```
ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 0, marginBottom: 90 }}></View>}
```

This is how I would do it, using the iPhoneX's height for now. But it's not future-proof since the conditional will need to be updated every time a new iPhone with no bezels comes out:

```
ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 0, marginBottom: noBezels ? 90 : 0 }}></View>}
```

Or you could just always have some spacing at the bottom, like a loading gif, a message... whatever.

**UPDATE 2:**

I found out about react-native-device-info which has a hasNotch() method. I find that useful for styling for iPhones with no bezels by combining hasNotch() with Platform.OS === 'ios'

Comment: Hi @jsonp unfortunately i didn't see your response but I solved it basically like you did. I wanted to thank you a little belated for your efforts, even when I was not able to read your message in time. So: thanks! (also upvoted)

Comment: Used this and it worked well, i was trying to add a View with set height under the flatlist component to no avail. This cleaned up my issue of the last list item being partially covered by my bottom nav.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry for the really late response. I'm not sure what you meant by breaking rules etc. If you see this could you explain?

Comment: @Yunnosch Gotcha. I'll keep that in mind moving forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

use **contentContainerStyle** props of FlatList

```
<FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20}} />
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try this solution

For `Vertical` `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
 ListFooterComponent={<View />}
 ListFooterComponentStyle={{height:200}}
/>
```

For `Horizontal` `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{paddingRight:40}}
/>
```

Answer (score 11):

For IOS issues you can apply some IOS specific props:

```
<FlatList
  // ...
  contentInset={{top: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0, right: 0}}
  contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
  // ...  
/>
```

The solution with `contentContainerStyle` padding didn't seem the best overall for fixing the safe area IOS issues in my case.

Comment: My flatlist was in a modal with a fixed height. this works better than any solution in my case.

Comment: It worked for me, also do not forget to add flex:1 for container of the FlatList

Answer (score 6):

Work very well for me

```javascript
<FlatList
  data={data}
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}
  style={{height: '95%'}}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <ListItem item={item} onPress={() => handlePress(item, index)} />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found the solution. To fix the issue just add `style={{flex: 1}}` for each View element who is a parent for `FlatList`.

See updated code below.

```javascript
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}> // Here you should add style as {flex: 1}
                <View style={Styles.viewStyle}>
                    <Text style={Styles.textStyle}>ProductsList</Text>
                </View>
                { this.renderProducts() }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the contentContainerStyle prop in the flatlist
`<FlatList  contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 10}} />`

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic flatlist, you can assign height to the parent view. I resolved it with same.

```
<View style={{height:'80%'}}>
  <Flatlist
    extraData={data}
    data={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
      style={{flex: 1}}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <ListItem item={item} onPress={() => handlePress(item)} />
      )}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it doing `contentInset={{ bottom: data.length * itemStyle.height, }}` with `itemStyle.height` being 50 worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

@krish solution is great for the fixed-size list items, however as
@Neeraj Sewani said, it may not be suitable for dynamic size list items.

so you can fix the issue like this -in case direction is column -:

```
<View  style={{height: '90%'}}> 
<FlatList/> 
</View>
```

Otherwise, -in case direction is row -:

```
<View  style={{height: '90%', width:'90%'}}> 
<FlatList/> 
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a 'flexGrow: 1' fixed my issue:

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
  // ...
/>
```

style:

container: {
alignItems: 'center',
flexGrow: 1
},

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same problem in our Android + iOS React Native hybrid app. We embed the FlatList component within our native UIs inside a Fragment in Android and we were unable to scroll to the last item in the list, even though the scroll indicator would show that there was more to scroll, the ScrollView would simply not scroll further. I tried all the combinations of using a wrapping `<View style={{flex:1}}>` to wrap the FlatList as well as using `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}` on the FlatList without success. Pursuing the clue further it turned out that the FlatList needs an absolute, predefined height on Android to allow scroll to the bottom - it works just fine on iOS but on Android using `match_parent` wasn't going to work. Since we need to support all types of devices, phone and tablet too, it wasn't possible to pre-define an absolute height either.

To fix this, I made a custom `FrameLayout` subclass to house the ReactRootView's fragment, which overrides `onLayout()` to ignore the child view measurements, forcing the views to have the exact dimensions of the FrameLayout, somewhat like so in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class StretchFrameLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        for (child in children){
            if (child.visibility == View.GONE) continue
            child.updateLayoutParams {
                this.width = measuredWidth
                this.height = measuredHeight
            }
            if (needsRelayout){
                handler.postDelayed({child.requestLayout()},1)
            }
        }
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a margin to the bottom of the flatlist.

`<FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ marginBottom: 50 }} />`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I used a mix of the above answers

First of all

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}
/>
```

and secondly, the parent View of FlatList should have `flex: 1`

So it looks like this

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
   <FlatList
       contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 20 }}
   />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap flatList with view tag, then style view tag with flex:1. it will work.

Answer (score -1):

This work very well in my case:

```
  <FlatList
    data={todos}
    contentContainerStyle={{ height: '100%' }}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Todos items={item} pressed={pressed} />}
  />
```

Comment: This blocks scrolling

Comment: Scrolling is not working with this solution